# SpriteKit enemy should move sideways

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, gravity

Where enemies are moving from every side to the screen. 
Falling enemies were easy to make with gravity.

But how can I make an enemy moving along the x axis or from down the screen to the top?

Comment: So I need to make a SKSpriteNode specific for a gravity setting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a SKAction for this:

```
let moveAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: 100, y: 100, duration: 2)
entity.run(moveAction)
```

This will move your node up and to the right.

Answer (score 0):

You may not want gravity then, turn off `affectedByGravity` on all of your enemy nodes, then use the SKAction `SKAction.moveBy(x:y:duration:)` to have you enemies move in a certain direction

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to move things through gravity, you could use Linear Gravity SKFieldNode https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skfieldnode

By create a 'vertical' Linear Gravity field and a 'Horizontal' linear field node and the correct use of the `fieldBitMask`, you could have some objects falling vertically as they are affected by the vertical gravity field and other objects 'falling' horizontally due to the horizontal gravity field.